# TFS Chained Gated Check In Builds

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Currently my TFS 2012 build environment features a Build Verification (BVT) build which mostly follows LabDefaultTemplate.xaml worfklow.  The BVT build first queues a Continuous Build (which mostly follows the DefaultTemplate.11.xaml), waits for that build to finish, then performs the necessary tests.

Now, I would like to change this BVT build to be Gated Check-In.  Which is to say, I don't want any changes to be committed until the BVT is successful.  The problem seems to be queuing the Continuous build definition in such a way that it will pick up the shelf set.  This logic appears to be dependent on the build being started with Reason = "CheckInShelveset".  However it seems all builds queued from another build always have Reason "UserCreated".  Has anyone found a way around this problem?  Is it possible to chain builds together while still having Gated Check-Ins?

Comment: How do you set up the chain build in TFS? So, is Gated Checkin build and CI build included in the chain build?

Comment: Gated Check-In build is following the LabDefaultTemplate which accepts the Lab Workflow Parameters.  This set of parameters includes a "Build" section with options for Queue New Build or Select an Existing Build.  In my case, this is set to Queue New Build and build definition = my continuous build.